# Tkinter lambda increment IntVar on Button Click

Tags: python, button, lambda, tkinter

**Problem Set**

I want to create a Counter widget that can be manipulated by 3 actions:

- Edit bound `tk.Entry-Textvariable` through editing the Data inside the `tk.Entry-Widget`
- Increment the Variable by clicking `ttk.Button` right to the Entry
- Decrement the variable by clicking `ttk.Button` left to the Entry

**Current Code**

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python2
    # -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
    import Tkinter as tk
    import ttk

    counter=tk.IntVar()

    def printerCounterWidget(master):
        """
        This will specify the appearance of the PrintCounter
        """

        #Create the UI
        __frame = ttk.Frame(master)
        __frame.grid()

        global counter
        ####################################################################
        ttk.Button(__frame, text="-", command=lambda: counter.set( counter.get() - 1 ) ).grid(row=0, column=0)
        ####################################################################

        ttk.Entry(__frame, textvariable=counter).grid(row=0, column=1)

        ####################################################################
        ttk.Button(__frame, text="+", command=lambda: counter.set( counter.get() + 1 ) ).grid(row=0, column=2)
        ####################################################################

    if __name__=="__main__":
        app=tk.Tk()
        ttk.Label(app, text="printerCounterWidget").grid()
        printerCounterWidget(app)
        app.mainloop()
```

Unfortunately I did not manage (at least yet) to get the lambda expression working.

I **do** know that the current call would never work as it is called at declaration time.

Can someone point me into the direction to set up the lambda expression correctly?

Comment: You're missing a colon: `lambda: counter...`

Comment: Thats completely correct! sry4that typo! I edited the question

Comment: Why are you using lambda here, instead of creating a proper function? Lambdas make code more difficult to write, read, and maintain.

Comment: Bryan: this "widget" should be used later on in a TkinterTreectrl View. That for I prefer the lambda over the proper callback based on the identification of event sender would take too long having > 20 000 Datasets (rows) inside the tree.

If you know a proper solution for that i would gladly appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, that was not long. I found the Issue after the lambdas had the colons attached.

counter=tk.IntVar() won't work inside the global version.
putting it into the function solved it.

```
    def printerCounterWidget():
        [...]
        counter=tk.IntVar() # removed "global counter"
        [...]
```